# GKE Where does Master Node runs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE cluster where does the master run.

I checked in the worker nodes of GKE. Only kube-proxy and kubelet services are running

Even kubelet.kubeconfig file referring server as one public ip. Which is no where defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GKE provides a hosted control plane for your cluster. The "master" for a cluster is really a collection of standard services (kube-apiserver, kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager) along with some environment specific controllers (ingress, autoscaling, etc). GKE hides the implementation of these services behind the cluster endpoint, which is how they are exposed to your nodes (kubelet and kube-proxy) and also you as the cluster user. GKE handles the provisioning of a public IP for the cluster endpoint and the configuration needed to make the the nodes communicate with it. The control plane is not run in your project so you don't see any of the underlying resources that are consumed running it.

If you would like full control over the configuration and deployment of your control plane (on a single "master" machine or spread across multiple "master" machines) you can use a community sponsored tool like [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) or [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray) to deploy your cluster.

Comment: Thanks Robert ...! Is it the same case with Aws eks and Azure aks... Does the Rancher 2.0 provides the master node control to us over these cloud providers.

Comment: EKS and AKS operate similarly to GKE where the control plane is offered as a managed service. I don't know enough about Rancher to know what they are doing to control the master. Some providers let you specify what version of Kubernetes it runs or toggle which addons are included.

Comment: this is a great answer! Could you also provide some documents on what you mentioned? Thanks!